# Invetstigate memory leak with Valgring output

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have a problem with a memory leak and the output of Valgrind:

```
==4501== 15,263,488 bytes in 59,623 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5,941 of 5,942
==4501==    at 0x4C2BBA0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4501==    by 0x6CC78D1: newlocale (newlocale.c:201)
==4501==    by 0x527EE7: app::TLocale::create(app::ELocale) (locale.cpp:141)
==4501==    by 0x5276AD: app::TLocale::TLocale() (locale.cpp:38)
==4501==    by 0x50091E: util::TDateTime::TDateTime(util::EDateTimeType) (datetime.cpp:828)
==4501==    by 0x587EE4: util::TVariant::TVariant() (variant.cpp:74)
==4501==    by 0x561215: data::TField::TField() (tables.cpp:193)
==4501==    by 0x554EA7: sqlite::TQuery::assignFields() (sqlite.cpp:631)
==4501==    by 0x553C80: sqlite::TQuery::next() (sqlite.cpp:415)
==4501==    by 0x4F8E06: sql::TDataQuery::fetchAll() (database.cpp:219)
==4501==    by 0x5CD499: app::TMain::qryPersonalData(std::string&, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::string const&, unsigned long) (main.cpp:1616)
==4501==    by 0x5CCF86: app::TMain::getPersonalData(app::TThreadData&, char const*&, unsigned long&, util::TNamedVariants&) (main.cpp:1568)
```

If i look at the first lines I would asume that `newlocale()` is used without `freelocale()`. But I checked the code again and again, this is not the case.

Am I misinterpreting the output and the leakage might be somewhere else?

Comment: And you're calling this `freelocale` function with the same pointer as `newlocale` returns? Do you call `newlocale` X times, but `freelocale` X-1 times? Does `freelocale` really call `free` on all memory allocated by `newlocale`?

Comment: I use `newlocale` in the ctor of the class TLocale and `freelocale`in the dtor of the same class. So there should be no problem. And the size of the memory leak is very hight compared to the count of locale objects used...

Comment: Or just use those smart pointers that were added to standard 5 years ago ;)

Comment: Then you probably need to examine the `newlocale` and `freelocale` functions.

Comment: Can you instrument `newlocale` and `freelocale`?

Comment: is there a case where you create a class and you never delete it? eg "new TLocale"

Comment: What do you mean with intrument `newlocale`?

Comment: E.g. count the number of times each is called, maybe even display the memory address - although you'd probably have to write another script/program to check the output. Have you implemented the copy/move constructor/assignment operator correctly?

Comment: Otherwise I'm with Chris and skyking: Are you sure you are not leaking on a higher level and can you provide some of the relevant code (constructors, destructors and assignment operators of the objects mentioned in the stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for all the hints. I will extend debug output and check the operators and ctors. I also think that the reason is not (only) caused by `newlocale`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the traceback it's not that obvious that pairing of `newlocale` and `freelocale` is the culprit. There's a number of constructors (`TLocale`, `TDateTime`, `TVariant` and `TField`) that would probably have to be destroyed as well (if the `freelocale` is called from the destructor). You should check that there is no memory leaks of those classes as well (for example if you have a `new TLocale` without `delete` you would get another memory leak detected).

More than that is hard to tell without seeing enough of the source code.

Comment: OK, it is important for me that you agree with the interpretation of the Valgind output. I will then investigate further in dtors of the classes...